# User dispatch:phoneformat.js Server-Side in Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the [`dispatch:phoneformat.js`](https://atmospherejs.com/dispatch/phoneformat.js) package. It works fine on the client side, but when I attempt to use it server side I get the following error: `[Error: Object #<Object> has no method 'formatE164']`

Looking at the GitHub repo, I believe it should work server-side "out-of-the-box"

I'm simply trying to call `Phoneformat.formatE164` from a Meteor method. It works fine if I call it from client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code on the package from https://github.com/DispatchMe/phoneformat.js/

The package does not support getting `formatE164` on the server side. The only server side methods are `Phoneformat.configure` which allows you to use the `phoneformat.getCountryForIp` method.

It looks a bit like the package was designed to be this way. You may have to request the author to modify it to be more isomorphic.

I suspect the `google.phoneformat.js` package its built from doesn't run on the server judging from the use of client side `window` code in the file. This may be why the method only works on the client side.